# Is there an accepted term for this style of management?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

There are terms for different management styles—for example *seagull management*, *mushroom management*, and *micromanagement*. What I am looking for is a term that describes management which changes well-established structures and procedures that have evolved to the point where they cannot be significantly improved. Such changes are usually for the worse or at best a pointless waste of effort. The terms *mismanagement* or *incompetent management* apply here but are too broad. The aim of this type of manager is apparently to “make their mark”: to show that the manager is a reformer, modernizer, or strategic thinker, display how energetic they are, or prove that they have achieved something they can point to.

As in management, the same phenomenon appears in design, where creativity can be added to the list of virtues to be demonstrated.

Comment: Disruptor-from-hell management?

Comment: Are you looking for a term for a “change-for-change’s-sake” style of management?

Comment: @TinfoilHat : Yes:  “change-for-change’s-sake management” would be somewhat close. However, it's not a standard phrase, and hardly elegant. Moreover, it imputes a motive: that the purpose is change. That may be the case, but I suggest that the motive is more often to demonstrate the manager's power. The best I can come up with is “busy management”, although that's not well enough discriminated from “micromanagement”.

Comment: _Destruct management_ [OED for 'destruct'](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/51110?redirectedFrom=destruct#eid) . . . .  _1969   Guardian 21 Jan. 2/3   He had asked for a ‘destruct’ system to be installed in the electronics and code area of the ship._. Up-voted +1. (Think 'destructuring' as a means of dissipation and self-assertion.)

Comment: How is 'Such changes are usually for the worse or at best a pointless waste of effort.…' not an unvalidated opinion and here, wholly irrelevant? Don't you think the whole idea would be better treated on some site dealing with management?

Comment: reinventing the wheel